# How to compile spread operator on older ts-node?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, azure, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to install some azure dependencies to an older app that is using `react-scripts-ts` to handle typescript. However, I am getting the following error:

I tried:

- Upgrading typescript (same erorr)
- Switching from deprecated `react-scripts-ts` to `react-scripts` ... could not get it to compile anything after that as it expects `js` instead of `ts` and I don't know how to configure if I am not creating a new app.

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@azure/msal-react/dist/msal-react.esm.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (141:11)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   }
| 
|   return { ...previousState,
|     inProgress: newInProgress,
|     accounts: newAccounts
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just doing `npx create-react-app new_folder --template typescript` and migrating all the `src` and other files there. Then tweaking `package.json` until I could compile again. There were a few dependencies I had to update too due to higher react and react-scripts... but nothing too bad luckily.